# Oracle date error ORA-01830

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle

Ruby code to select record by date interval:

```
monthly_activity = activity.trn_activity_items.find_by(
  'month >= ? AND month < ?',
  activity.daily_stat_date.beginning_of_month,
  activity.daily_stat_date.end_of_month
)
```

All works fine on mysql and postgres, but Oracle seems to don`t like something and i cant understand what exactly.

Oracle error:

```
OCIError: ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string: SELECT  "TRN_ACTIVITY_ITEMS".* FROM "TRN_ACTIVITY_ITEMS" WHERE "TRN_ACTIVITY_ITEMS"."TRN_ACTIVITY_ID" = :a1 AND (month >= '2017-07-01 00:00:00' AND month < '2017-07-31 23:59:59.999999') AND ROWNUM <= :a2
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `'2017-07-31 23:59:59.999999'`

Oracle dates don't have fractional seconds (although timestamps do). So your query should look like this:

```
AND month <= '2017-07-31 23:59:59')
```

Although if you want to maintain compatibility with those other databases probably you don't want to use less than or equal, in which case you should specify the upper bound as

```
AND month < '2017-08-01 00:00:00'
```

Alternatively, you could to change the column declaration so it has a timestamp datatype. Depends on your use case.